# How can I pass a vector of strings in as separate arguments of a function in R?

Tags: r

Say that I am using a function which takes in an arbitrary number of objects, such as `expand.grid()`. Now let's say that I have various lists saved within an environment, such that calling `ls()` on the environment provides the string representation for all of the lists within the environment. Is there a manner in which I can pass all of the the lists from the environment directly into the function?

Comment: Maybe `do.call(expand.grid, mget(ls()))`?

Comment: Thank you, this worked in my case with `do.call(expand.grid, mget(ls(my_env), envir = my_env)` as the variables were further enclosed within another environment. I was previously trying something along the lines of `expand.grid(eval(parse(text = paste("my_env$",ls(my_env)))))` but only the final part of the expression was being evaluated.